# Updating Client and Domain password domain and vpn

Tags: active-directory, vpn

Win server 2003 R2 and Windows 7 Pro on VPN. Client computer will never been in domain without VPN.

When I press ctrl+alt+del, and enter the new password i get the error:

Unable to update password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain.

I can assure you the password enter does meet length, complexity, and history requirements of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Part of most complexity schema's is that you cannot use the same password you have used since X, and X amount of last passwords. Have you checked what the complexity requirements are for this server?

From memory I think that this is the last 12 passwords cannot be used. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Additionally there can be a restriction where you can only change the password x times a day. If this limit is exceeded you recieve the exact same message as OP